# How do I get back the old facebook messenger emoji in messenger.com?

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger, emoji

[image]

The ones on the left are the old emoji I used to have and liked, but now the emoji look like the ones on the right. What do I do to continue seeing the old ones? Is it possible to go back to the older version?

This is on messenger.com on desktop.